# What was the number of native casualties in the Muslim invasion of Hispania?

Tags: middle-ages, war, spain, portugal

Where can I find information about the number of casualties amongst native peoples produced by the Muslim invasion of Visigothic Hispania?

Strangely, it's very easy to get an estimate of the number of casualties in most other wars and genocides, including some much older ones that happened in America or Greece, but no information about the invasion of Hispania, just some sparse data on some battles and sieges.

Comment: Two things: 1) Requests for sources are usually off-topic. Consider editing this to simply ask what the casualties were. Answers are expected to be sourced anyway. 2) This is an event that happened at nearly the "darkest" period of the Dark Ages, and in one of the least literate corners of both cultures. Its tough to get straight information on the battles themselves.

Comment: low and disperse, the "invasion" was mostly a change of rulers, a milder version of the danish invasion of brittania. To give an example,the ruling roman family on most of hispania during the late empire, the Cassius,  renamed themselves as the Goth Cassios, became the muslim ruler dinasty of the Banu-Qasi.  Both the muslim invasion and the christian reconquista had been vastly mitified during the late 19th century and the spanish dictatorship,as  both were formed by small or miniscule local conflicts between elites that didn't had strong impact on the population, as archeology studies show.

Comment: Most current spanish Historians agree that the conquest of Al-Andalus was due to a great client network created prior to the invasion and the use of those visigoth clients and allies to perform the most harsh and crude miltiary operations, leaving the small invasion forces ( an estimated 4.000 to  16.000 men) to pacify, rule and assemble the future governed territories.

Comment: i reccomend this doctoral thesis.  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/262686964_La_Espana_perdida_El_discurso_sobre_moros_y_cristianos

Comment: You are right. There is no enough information.